# Hoisting the dynamic type out of a loop (a.k.a. doing Java the C++ way)

Tags: c++, virtual

I was discussing the merits of "modern" languages compared to C++ with some friends recently, when the following came up (I think inspired by Java):

Does any C++ compiler optimize dynamic dispatch out of a loop? If not, is there any kind of construction that would allow the author to force (or strongly encourage) such an optimization?

Here's the example. Suppose I have a polymorphic hierarchy:

```
struct A { virtual int f() { return 0; } };

struct B : A { virtual int f() { return /* something complicated */; } /*...*/ };
```

Now I have a loop that accumulates `f()`:

```
int acc(const A * p, unsigned int N)
{
  int result = 0;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    result += p->f();  // #1

  return result;
}
```

In this function, the dynamic dispatch `p->f()` appears to happen during every round of the loop. However, the ultimate target of the dispatch blatantly (?) cannot vary.

Question: Does this dynamic dispatch get optimized by the compiler? If not, is there any way to rewrite the code to force this optimization, or at least enable the compiler to recognize this? Is there any good test code that can tell me quickly whether this is getting optimized already?

I'm interested in both language and implementation answers, such as "this is impossible according to the standard", or "yes, MSVC does this with option `/xyzzy`".

<sub>Some comparative remarks: Apparently Java does optimize and even *inline* the call in the inner loop if appropriate. Objective-C++ apparently allows you to query the dynamic function pointer and store it.</sub>

*Clarification:* The main use case which I'm interested in is when the base class and the function with the loop (like the accumulator) are part of a separate translation unit or library, and there is no control over or knowledge of the derived classes.

Comment: noone does these dynamic hierarchies any longer. It's all templates now. The template version does not have this problem.

Comment: @tp1: Hm. That's a strong statement. Templates and inheritance are essentially orthogonal concepts, so I would object to your implication that you can casually swap one for the other.

Comment: I don't think you can inline a virtual function called from a pointer. Easiest way to check with gcc is to make the array very large, then turn on -funroll-loops and -finline-functions, if it takes a long time to compile, and a very short amount of time to execute, then it might be getting resolved at compile time. Seems like a long-shot though. Still, I'd be very interested in seeing a proper answer to this.

Comment: @Darcy: I'm not really hoping for inlining - that was only a remark about Java. The JVM *can* actually re-inline code at runtime, but I'm not expecting that from a C++ program.

Comment: well in this specific case you can implement the accumulation inside the class, or you could use casting to determine the type of *p, cast it and then call f()

Comment: @galchen: Imagine that the base class and the accumulator are part as a library and don't know who's deriving.

Comment: just brainstorming - how about using a pointer to the member function?

Comment: Tried g++ 4.6.1 with `-flto -fwhole-program -O3` and still it wouldn't hoist the vtable lookup out of the loop.  Hard to say if it's not smart enough or if it thinks that with a tight loop and a hot cache it's not worth hoisting

Comment: @Lambdageek: Yeah, it's tricky to even come up with a decent test code that would show a significant difference...

Comment: forget about using pointer to member function: "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function."

Comment: HAve you checked to see what the compiler does?

Comment: @Tux-D: I'm having trouble setting up a test that would tell me the difference. Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: Can you just compile the above code into assembly. Then manually look at the assembly to see if it is going through the full look up each time through the loop or weather it cashes the lookup (of the method) outside the loop.

Comment: @Tux: I've tried something like that, but I don't know how to tell dynamic lookup from a direct call -- or I may just not have succeeded at writing a good test program. I tried adding a static-cast to `B*`, but that gave me the exact same assembly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I compiled the above code:

The only change I made was to make the methods const as the parameter 'p' to acc() was also const.
When I compiled it (on a macbook) using g++ 4.2.1 and -O3 I get the following code (this looks like the loop in acc()).

Does not look like it is chaining through the lookup table.
It is a simple get via a register that already has vtable set up.

```
 57 L9:
 58     movq    (%r12), %rax   // Get the location of f() method address via the r12 register
 59     movq    %r12, %rdi     // Set up rdi register as `this` (for after call)
 60     call    *(%rax)        // Call the F() method. address is in memory pointed at by rax
 61     addl    %eax, %r14d
 62     incl    %ebx
 63     cmpl    %r13d, %ebx
 64     jne L9
```

If I remove the virtual descriptors from the lines the same code is:

```
 76 L16:
 77     movq    %r14, %rdi     // Set up rdi register as `this` (for after call)
 78     call    __ZNK1A1fEv    // Call the F() method.
 79     addl    %eax, %r13d
 80     incl    %ebx
 81     cmpl    %r12d, %ebx
 82     jne L16
```

So the difference in the above code is really:

```
movq    (%r12), %rax     This is a register to register copy.
                         The cost of this is practically nothing and you could never
                         detect it. No matter how many times you called the function.

call    *(%rax)          Here we have to look up the address to call by getting it
                         from memory. Now this could be expensive.

                         But in reality is not. The first time this is called the
                         memory will be placed in an in-chip memory cache (if it is
                         not there you will get a processor stall while it is loaded
                         from memory (or the next cache up)) but after that it will
                         be really fast.

                         But it is not quite as fast as just calling the address (for
                         the non virtual version). But the difference is insignificant
                         and other factors in the code will drown out any gains or
                         just in pure noise of the measurements.
```

So to answer the question. No the address of the function is not cached for re-use. It is looked up each time through the loop.

Source that was compiled:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { virtual int f() const { return 0; } };

struct B : A { virtual int f() const { return 1; }};

int acc(const A * p, unsigned int N)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
        result += p->f();  // #1

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    A       a;
    B       b;
    std::cout << acc(&a, 20) << "\n";
    std::cout << acc(&b, 22) << "\n";
}
```

Full Assembley:

```
  1     .mod_init_func
  2     .align 3
  3     .quad   __GLOBAL__I__Z3accPK1Aj
  4     .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
  5     .align 1
  6     .align 4
  7 .globl __ZNK1A1fEv
  8     .weak_definition __ZNK1A1fEv
  9 __ZNK1A1fEv:
 10 LFB1477:
 11     pushq   %rbp
 12 LCFI0:
 13     movq    %rsp, %rbp
 14 LCFI1:
 15     xorl    %eax, %eax
 16     leave
 17     ret
 18 LFE1477:
 19     .align 1
 20     .align 4
 21 .globl __ZNK1B1fEv
 22     .weak_definition __ZNK1B1fEv
 23 __ZNK1B1fEv:
 24 LFB1478:
 25     pushq   %rbp
 26 LCFI2:
 27     movq    %rsp, %rbp
 28 LCFI3:
 29     movl    $1, %eax
 30     leave
 31     ret
 32 LFE1478:
 33     .text
 34     .align 4,0x90
 35 .globl __Z3accPK1Aj
 36 __Z3accPK1Aj:
 37 LFB1479:
 38     pushq   %rbp
 39 LCFI4:
 40     movq    %rsp, %rbp
 41 LCFI5:
 42     pushq   %r14
 43 LCFI6:
 44     pushq   %r13
 45 LCFI7:
 46     pushq   %r12
 47 LCFI8:
 48     pushq   %rbx
 49 LCFI9:
 50     movq    %rdi, %r12
 51     movl    %esi, %r13d
 52     xorl    %r14d, %r14d
 53     testl   %esi, %esi
 54     je  L8
 55     xorl    %ebx, %ebx
 56     .align 4,0x90
 57 L9:
 58     movq    (%r12), %rax
 59     movq    %r12, %rdi
 60     call    *(%rax)
 61     addl    %eax, %r14d
 62     incl    %ebx
 63     cmpl    %r13d, %ebx
 64     jne L9
 65 L8:
 66     movl    %r14d, %eax
 67     popq    %rbx
 68     popq    %r12
 69     popq    %r13
 70     popq    %r14
 71     leave
 72     ret
 73 LFE1479:
 74     .section __TEXT,__StaticInit,regular,pure_instructions
 75     .align 4
 76 __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
 77 LFB1649:
 78     pushq   %rbp
 79 LCFI10:
 80     movq    %rsp, %rbp
 81 LCFI11:
 82     decl    %edi
 83     je  L18
 84 L17:
 85     leave
 86     ret
 87     .align 4
 88 L18:
 89     cmpl    $65535, %esi
 90     jne L17
 91     leaq    __ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rdi
 92     call    __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
 93     movq    ___dso_handle@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
 94     xorl    %esi, %esi
 95     leaq    ___tcf_0(%rip), %rdi
 96     leave
 97     jmp ___cxa_atexit
 98 LFE1649:
 99     .align 4
100 __GLOBAL__I__Z3accPK1Aj:
101 LFB1651:
102     pushq   %rbp
103 LCFI12:
104     movq    %rsp, %rbp
105 LCFI13:
106     movl    $65535, %esi
107     movl    $1, %edi
108     leave
109     jmp __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
110 LFE1651:
111     .text
112     .align 4,0x90
113 ___tcf_0:
114 LFB1650:
115     pushq   %rbp
116 LCFI14:
117     movq    %rsp, %rbp
118 LCFI15:
119     leaq    __ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rdi
120     leave
121     jmp __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
122 LFE1650:
123     .cstring
124 LC0:
125     .ascii "\12\0"
126     .text
127     .align 4,0x90
128 .globl _main
129 _main:
130 LFB1480:
131     pushq   %rbp
132 LCFI16:
133     movq    %rsp, %rbp
134 LCFI17:
135     pushq   %r14
136 LCFI18:
137     pushq   %r13
138 LCFI19:
139     pushq   %r12
140 LCFI20:
141     pushq   %rbx
142 LCFI21:
143     subq    $32, %rsp
144 LCFI22:
145     movq    __ZTV1A@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
146     addq    $16, %rax
147     movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
148     movq    __ZTV1B@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
149     addq    $16, %rax
150     movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
151     leaq    -48(%rbp), %r13
152     movq    %r13, %rdi
153     call    __ZNK1A1fEv
154     movl    %eax, %ebx
155     movl    $1, %r12d
156     .align 4,0x90
157 L24:
158     movq    %r13, %rdi
159     call    __ZNK1A1fEv
160     addl    %eax, %ebx
161     incl    %r12d
162     cmpl    $20, %r12d
163     jne L24
164     movl    %ebx, %esi
165     movq    __ZSt4cout@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r14
166     movq    %r14, %rdi
167     call    __ZNSolsEi
168     movq    %rax, %rdi
169     movl    $1, %edx
170     leaq    LC0(%rip), %rsi
171     call    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
172     leaq    -64(%rbp), %r13
173     movq    %r13, %rdi
174     movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
175     call    *(%rax)
176     movl    %eax, %ebx
177     movb    $1, %r12b
178     .align 4,0x90
179 L26:
180     movq    %r13, %rdi
181     movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
182     call    *(%rax)
183     addl    %eax, %ebx
184     incl    %r12d
185     cmpl    $22, %r12d
186     jne L26
187     movl    %ebx, %esi
188     movq    %r14, %rdi
189     call    __ZNSolsEi
190     movq    %rax, %rdi
191     movl    $1, %edx
192     leaq    LC0(%rip), %rsi
193     call    __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
194     xorl    %eax, %eax
195     addq    $32, %rsp
196     popq    %rbx
197     popq    %r12
198     popq    %r13
199     popq    %r14
200     leave
201     ret
202 LFE1480:
203 .lcomm __ZStL8__ioinit,1,0
204 .globl __ZTV1A
205     .weak_definition __ZTV1A
206     .section __DATA,__const_coal,coalesced
207     .align 4
208 __ZTV1A:
209     .quad   0
210     .quad   __ZTI1A
211     .quad   __ZNK1A1fEv
212 .globl __ZTI1A
213     .weak_definition __ZTI1A
214     .align 4
215 __ZTI1A:
216     .quad   __ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE+16
217     .quad   __ZTS1A
218 .globl __ZTS1A
219     .weak_definition __ZTS1A
220     .section __TEXT,__const_coal,coalesced
221 __ZTS1A:
222     .ascii "1A\0"
223 .globl __ZTV1B
224     .weak_definition __ZTV1B
225     .section __DATA,__const_coal,coalesced
226     .align 4
227 __ZTV1B:
228     .quad   0
229     .quad   __ZTI1B
230     .quad   __ZNK1B1fEv
231 .globl __ZTI1B
232     .weak_definition __ZTI1B
233     .align 4
234 __ZTI1B:
235     .quad   __ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE+16
236     .quad   __ZTS1B
237     .quad   __ZTI1A
238 .globl __ZTS1B
239     .weak_definition __ZTS1B
240     .section __TEXT,__const_coal,coalesced
241 __ZTS1B:
242     .ascii "1B\0"
243     .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
244 EH_frame1:
245     .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
246     .long L$set$0
247 LSCIE1:
248     .long   0x0
249     .byte   0x1
250     .ascii "zPR\0"
251     .byte   0x1
252     .byte   0x78
253     .byte   0x10
254     .byte   0x6
255     .byte   0x9b
256     .long   ___gxx_personality_v0+4@GOTPCREL
257     .byte   0x10
258     .byte   0xc
259     .byte   0x7
260     .byte   0x8
261     .byte   0x90
262     .byte   0x1
263     .align 3
264 LECIE1:
265 .globl __ZNK1A1fEv.eh
266     .weak_definition __ZNK1A1fEv.eh
267 __ZNK1A1fEv.eh:
268 LSFDE1:
269     .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
270     .long L$set$1
271 LASFDE1:
272     .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
273     .quad   LFB1477-.
274     .set L$set$2,LFE1477-LFB1477
275     .quad L$set$2
276     .byte   0x0
277     .byte   0x4
278     .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB1477
279     .long L$set$3
280     .byte   0xe
281     .byte   0x10
282     .byte   0x86
283     .byte   0x2
284     .byte   0x4
285     .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
286     .long L$set$4
287     .byte   0xd
288     .byte   0x6
289     .align 3
290 LEFDE1:
291 .globl __ZNK1B1fEv.eh
292     .weak_definition __ZNK1B1fEv.eh
293 __ZNK1B1fEv.eh:
294 LSFDE3:
295     .set L$set$5,LEFDE3-LASFDE3
296     .long L$set$5
297 LASFDE3:
298     .long   LASFDE3-EH_frame1
299     .quad   LFB1478-.
300     .set L$set$6,LFE1478-LFB1478
301     .quad L$set$6
302     .byte   0x0
303     .byte   0x4
304     .set L$set$7,LCFI2-LFB1478
305     .long L$set$7
306     .byte   0xe
307     .byte   0x10
308     .byte   0x86
309     .byte   0x2
310     .byte   0x4
311     .set L$set$8,LCFI3-LCFI2
312     .long L$set$8
313     .byte   0xd
314     .byte   0x6
315     .align 3
316 LEFDE3:
317 .globl __Z3accPK1Aj.eh
318 __Z3accPK1Aj.eh:
319 LSFDE5:
320     .set L$set$9,LEFDE5-LASFDE5
321     .long L$set$9
322 LASFDE5:
323     .long   LASFDE5-EH_frame1
324     .quad   LFB1479-.
325     .set L$set$10,LFE1479-LFB1479
326     .quad L$set$10
327     .byte   0x0
328     .byte   0x4
329     .set L$set$11,LCFI4-LFB1479
330     .long L$set$11
331     .byte   0xe
332     .byte   0x10
333     .byte   0x86
334     .byte   0x2
335     .byte   0x4
336     .set L$set$12,LCFI5-LCFI4
337     .long L$set$12
338     .byte   0xd
339     .byte   0x6
340     .byte   0x4
341     .set L$set$13,LCFI9-LCFI5
342     .long L$set$13
343     .byte   0x83
344     .byte   0x6
345     .byte   0x8c
346     .byte   0x5
347     .byte   0x8d
348     .byte   0x4
349     .byte   0x8e
350     .byte   0x3
351     .align 3
352 LEFDE5:
353 __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii.eh:
354 LSFDE7:
355     .set L$set$14,LEFDE7-LASFDE7
356     .long L$set$14
357 LASFDE7:
358     .long   LASFDE7-EH_frame1
359     .quad   LFB1649-.
360     .set L$set$15,LFE1649-LFB1649
361     .quad L$set$15
362     .byte   0x0
363     .byte   0x4
364     .set L$set$16,LCFI10-LFB1649
365     .long L$set$16
366     .byte   0xe
367     .byte   0x10
368     .byte   0x86
369     .byte   0x2
370     .byte   0x4
371     .set L$set$17,LCFI11-LCFI10
372     .long L$set$17
373     .byte   0xd
374     .byte   0x6
375     .align 3
376 LEFDE7:
377 __GLOBAL__I__Z3accPK1Aj.eh:
378 LSFDE9:
379     .set L$set$18,LEFDE9-LASFDE9
380     .long L$set$18
381 LASFDE9:
382     .long   LASFDE9-EH_frame1
383     .quad   LFB1651-.
384     .set L$set$19,LFE1651-LFB1651
385     .quad L$set$19
386     .byte   0x0
387     .byte   0x4
388     .set L$set$20,LCFI12-LFB1651
389     .long L$set$20
390     .byte   0xe
391     .byte   0x10
392     .byte   0x86
393     .byte   0x2
394     .byte   0x4
395     .set L$set$21,LCFI13-LCFI12
396     .long L$set$21
397     .byte   0xd
398     .byte   0x6
399     .align 3
400 LEFDE9:
401 ___tcf_0.eh:
402 LSFDE11:
403     .set L$set$22,LEFDE11-LASFDE11
404     .long L$set$22
405 LASFDE11:
406     .long   LASFDE11-EH_frame1
407     .quad   LFB1650-.
408     .set L$set$23,LFE1650-LFB1650
409     .quad L$set$23
410     .byte   0x0
411     .byte   0x4
412     .set L$set$24,LCFI14-LFB1650
413     .long L$set$24
414     .byte   0xe
415     .byte   0x10
416     .byte   0x86
417     .byte   0x2
418     .byte   0x4
419     .set L$set$25,LCFI15-LCFI14
420     .long L$set$25
421     .byte   0xd
422     .byte   0x6
423     .align 3
424 LEFDE11:
425 .globl _main.eh
426 _main.eh:
427 LSFDE13:
428     .set L$set$26,LEFDE13-LASFDE13
429     .long L$set$26
430 LASFDE13:
431     .long   LASFDE13-EH_frame1
432     .quad   LFB1480-.
433     .set L$set$27,LFE1480-LFB1480
434     .quad L$set$27
435     .byte   0x0
436     .byte   0x4
437     .set L$set$28,LCFI16-LFB1480
438     .long L$set$28
439     .byte   0xe
440     .byte   0x10
441     .byte   0x86
442     .byte   0x2
443     .byte   0x4
444     .set L$set$29,LCFI17-LCFI16
445     .long L$set$29
446     .byte   0xd
447     .byte   0x6
448     .byte   0x4
449     .set L$set$30,LCFI22-LCFI17
450     .long L$set$30
451     .byte   0x83
452     .byte   0x6
453     .byte   0x8c
454     .byte   0x5
455     .byte   0x8d
456     .byte   0x4
457     .byte   0x8e
458     .byte   0x3
459     .align 3
460 LEFDE13:
461     .constructor
462     .destructor
463     .align 1
464     .subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Thanks for working this through! See my comment to Xavier's answer: Does the call through `*(%rax)` have hidden costs in terms of blocking the local instruction pipeline? In any event, it looks like one could manually save `*(%rax)` into a separate local register and use that -- perhaps this could be wrapped into a small inlined helper function?

Comment: @Kerrik SB: You now have enough code to actually profile the differences. Don't forget the cost of saving the register (before the function call) and restoring that register (after the function call) you have no idea what registers will be used in the function so the registers must be saved/restored into memory.

Comment: Thanks again. I used this sample program and modified the assembly to take the `movq (%r12), %rax` outside the loop (using an unused register in place of `rax`). However, there's no difference in the runtime. I think this test case is far too small to create any cache miss or misprediction effects...

Comment: `movq (%r12), %rax` is NOT a register to register copy -- it loads the value pointed at by %r12 into %rax.  However, since the value loaded is only used by the call, and the call will be predicted by the BTB, there's no load latency at all.  The only cost is the extra instruction decode which takes zero time as most x86 processors can decode two movs and a call in 1 cycle, so its using a decode slot that is just wasted in the second case.

Answer (score 8):

If you're interested in this kind of thing, check out Agner Fog's excellent [Software Optimization Manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).  This question is tangentially addressed in the first of the five, [Optimizing C++ (pdf)](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) (the others are all about assembly - he's kind of old-school).

If `f()` is a `const` function, or its return value when called on `p` is otherwise guaranteed to be unchanged, it can be pulled out of the loop and only calculated once (see "Loop Invariant Code Motion", page 70).  Most compilers will do this (see "Comparison of Different Compilers", page 74).

If that can't be done, then it might still be possible to devirtualize.  But this can't be done in a callable function, because that would *have* to use a virtual lookup for the sake of correctness.  But if the function was inlined, and the type of `p` was known in the calling scope, it could be done.  The calling code would have to look something like this:

```
A* aptr = new A(42); // <- The compiler knows exactly what type aptr points to
acc(a, 100);         // <- This would have to be inlined!
```

But according to that table (page 74), only the GCC compilers make this optimization.

Finally, the closest optimization (I think) to what you're asking.  Could the compiler perform the virtual lookup once, store a function pointer, and then use that function pointer to avoid the virtual lookup inside the loop?  I don't see why not.  But I don't know if any compilers do so - it's an obscure enough optimization that it's not even mentioned in Agner Fog's compulsively detailed C++ manual.

For what it's worth, here's what he has to say about function pointers (page 38):

> Calling a function through a function pointer typically takes a few
>   clock cycles more than calling the function directly if the target
>   address can be predicted. The target address is predicted if the value
>   of the function pointer is the same as last time the statement was
>   executed. If the value of the function pointer has changed then the
>   target address is likely to be mispredicted, which causes a long
>   delay. See page 44 about branch prediction. A Pentium M processor may
>   be able to predict the target if the changes of the function pointer
>   follows a simple regular pattern, while Pentium 4 and AMD processors
>   are sure to make a misprediction every time the function pointer has
>   changed.

And an excerpt about virtual member functions (page 54):

> The time it takes to call a virtual member function is a few clock
>   cycles more than it takes to call a non-virtual member function,
>   provided that the function call statement always calls the same
>   version of the virtual function. If the version changes then you may
>   get a misprediction penalty of 10 - 20 clock cycles. The rules for
>   prediction and misprediction of virtual function calls is the same as
>   for switch statements, as explained on page 45.
>
> The dispatching mechanism can be bypassed when the virtual function is
>   called on an object of known type, but you cannot always rely on the
>   compiler bypassing the dispatch mechanism even when it would be
>   obvious to do so. See page 73.

You know the function pointer wouldn't change in your example, so you wouldn't get the misprediction penalty, but he never compares function pointer performance to virtual function performance directly.  Both just take "a few" more clock cycles than a regular function call.  Maybe it's the same mechanism - if so, that "optimization" would just be adding an extra lookup.

So it's hard to say, really.  The best way to get an answer might just be to have your favourite compiler spit out some optimized assembly and dig through it (unpleasant, but conclusive!).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this! I've been told that the virtual lookup does incur secondary penalties such as having to flush and rebuild the entire instruction pipeline, so it can get reasonably expensive. Would a correct prediction avoid this, i.e. would the penalty only apply during the first round of the loop?

Comment: @Kerrek - It sounds like virtual function prediction works a lot like branch prediction - the CPU will make a guess as to which function ends up getting called, to keep the pipeline full, with the caveat that it'll have to flush the pipeline if it guesses wrong.  Since the "guess" will be "same as the last time we called this" for most CPUs, I think you're right - you'll probably only get the misprediction penalty once, the first time through the loop.  Cheers!

Comment: OK, prize question: How can I check whether there's a misprediction? Is there a tool like `predictgrind` that'll simulate this? :-)

Comment: "Could the compiler perform the virtual lookup once, store a function pointer, and then use that function pointer to avoid the virtual lookup inside the loop? I don't see why not." The _why not_ is because the compiler can't assume `p` will point at the same object same through the loop as when it began. It can't know if other translation units are altering `p` by placement `new` or changing it through another pointer. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14757633/2757035) It shouldn't make these assumptions for us! If you think the pointers won't change, cache the funcptr yourself first. Then profile.

Answer (score 1):

It has been pointed out to me that GCC has an extension, called ["bound member functions"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html), that does indeed allow you to store the actual function pointer. Demo:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() { }
    virtual int f(int, int) = 0;
};

void f(Foo & x)
{
    using gcc_func_type = int (*)(Foo *, int, int);

    gcc_func_type fp = (gcc_func_type)(x.*&Foo::f);  // !

    for ( /* ... */ )
    {
        int result = fp(&x, 10, 20);   // no virtual dispatch!
    }
}
```

The syntax requires that you go through a pointer-to-member indirection (i.e. you cannot just write `(x.f)`), and the cast must be a C-style cast. The resulting function pointer has the type of a pointer to a free function, with the instance argument taken as the first parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the required template version:

```
struct A { int f() const { return 0; } };
template<class T>
struct B { B(T &t) : t(t) { } int f() const { return t.f()+1; } T &t; };

template<class T>
int acc(const T *p, unsigned int N)
{
   int result = 0;

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
     result += p->f();
   return result;
}
```

And usage is:

```
int main() {
   A a;
   B<A> obj(a);
   int result = acc(&obj, 10);
}
```

Comment: Gcc spits this error out: "template.hpp:3: error: cannot call member function 'int A::f() const' without object"

Comment: That does not *answer* the question (although it solves the problem). In a more complicated scenario you wont be able/willing to replace polymorphic inheritance.