# c++ check function is overloaded or not in runtime

Tags: c++, virtual

I have an abstract interface `I` in which `virtual void Foo()` is defined, along with other functions. There are some subclasses in which `Foo` is re-defined, and others in which `Foo` is not. Now, given `I* pi`, is it possible to know whether `Foo` is re-defined? That is, I want to know whether  `pi->Foo()` would call `I::Foo()` or `X::Foo()` where `X` is some type in which `Foo` is re-defined. I think this can be done by comparing function pointers, between `&I::Foo` and `&pi->Foo`, but not sure exactly how to. Note that I don't know the concrete type of `pi` in runtime, so I cannot compare function pointers directly by `&I::Foo != &X::Foo`.

ADD:
So, a lot of people pointed that the design is bad, against the concept of abstraction and virtual functions. The main reason that I'm doing this is to bypass empty function calls to improve speed. Since some of `Foo()` are empty, I would like to remove it from a vector of `pi`s, when `Foo()` is empty.

Comment: Why? If you call the function you will see if it ends up in `I::foo`. Then you'll know!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  I smell bad design.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot store the result of a dynamic dispatch. I had a [question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451442/hoisting-the-dynamic-type-out-of-a-loop-a-k-a-doing-java-the-c-way) at some point. You *can* do it in Objective-C++, though.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of abstraction **not** to know this? Why do you need it?

Comment: No, you can't. And you shouldn't.

Comment: This would be useful to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find out from `&pi->Foo`, since, as the GCC error message will tell you,

> ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.

If you want to know the type of an object at runtime, use `typeid`. Otherwise, rethink your design.

Comment: Even if you use `typeid` you can't tell if a function is overriden

Comment: @SethCarnegie: no, but you can enumerate the types which have overridden a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can `dynamic_cast` your pointer to each of the child types that overrides `Foo` and if it's one of those types it will call the child. You can't take the address of a member function using the `->` syntax you want to use.

But all that said I would really rethink your design before doing something like this. The point of interfaces and virtual methods is to avoid the need to know what type you're dealing with!